# How to run single integration test in maven?

Tags: java, maven, mockito, integration-testing

I am trying run single integration test. I have a a lot of *IT class and I  want to run only one test. I try this :

```
mvn -Dit.test=XControllerIT verify
```

Am I doing wrong? Is there another alternative to this? Maven is being used.

Comment: Are you using maven-failsafe-plugin ? Furthermore does this test exist? What shows the output ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two main options depending on your project setup:

- Integration Tests are run with a dedicated Failsafe plugin
- Integration Tests are run with a regular surefire plugin

If you have a failsafe plugin (and you actually should, its a recommended approach), then use the following snippet:

```
mvn -Dit.test=MySampleIntegrationTest failsafe:integration-test
```

If you're on surefire, then run:

```
mvn -Dtest=MySampleUnitTest surefire:test
```

In both cases there is a direct plugin goal execution, bypassing the lifecycle like in your initial example (with `mvn verify`)

In maven it is possible to run the lifecycle, see [Default Lifecycle Documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) for more information

Basically, the lifecycle is comprised of phases with plugins bound to each phase
So when you run the **mvn verify** all the phases before verify will also run.

As a consequence, the code will be compiled (compile phase with a maven compile plugin automatically attached to it will do the job), tests will run (surefire plugin), and so on.

If you don't have a compiled source code and code of tests, you can't use the presented approach because you have to compile the code first.

However, if you already have everything compiled, it makes sense to run only the one test without recompilation of the code, and in this case, depending on the plugin you can use the suggested solution.

Especially it can make sense for local debugging or for CI in some cases multi-step build setup (can be seen in fairly complicated projects)

Comment: You shouldn't bypass the life cycle there is an intention behind that...first running unit tests and afterwards the integration tests...

Comment: @khmarbaise: Sorry, but bypassing the lifecycle can be a totally acceptable solution when there is an intention to do so. Maven can perfectly deal with it, of course, it's not always required. I'm perfectly aware of the intention behind the lifecycle. I've updated the answer to clarify the when the suggested solution is applicable  (and as I understood from the question, it was exactly the case) and when it isn't. Please read the answer and decide whether you still want to downvote ;)

Comment: @khmarbaise I agree with Mark Bramnik. Bypassing the life cycle is acceptable in certain situations. Example: troubleshooting. Getting everything to work can be challenging and it is OK, while troubleshooting, to skip the stuff that you are not interested in.